# Refresh fails for different angular app in main domain & sub domain .htaccess

Tags: angular, .htaccess, subdomain, web-hosting, page-refresh

I am working on two angular apps, one is in main domain `domain.com`, the other one is in sub-domain(For SEO reasons) `sub-domain.domain.com`. In main domain, accessing `index.html` & angular routes work perfectly, also refresh works here. But when accessing sub-domain with `sub-domain.domain.com`, `index.html` in `sub-domain-folder` opens & also angular routes in this app work nicely, but **refresh in any page in sub-domain gives me a 500 error**.

My App structure in CPanel Hosting:

```
  /public_html (main domain, angular app)
   |-index.html
   |-assets
   |-other app-1 files
   |-sub-domain-folder/ (sub domain, separate angular app)
      |-index.html
      |-app-2 files
```

My .htaccess file:
To redirect all calls to main domain to index.html (angular routes). Refresh works here:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

for sub-domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub-domain\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub-domain-folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /sub-domain-folder/$1
```

When I access sub-domain.domain.com, browser correctly navigates to `sub-domain.domain.com/home`
as expected, also all angular routes are working here. However refresh the page here gives me a 500 internal server error.

I want to generate sitemap.xml with angular routes in sub-domain.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Fix was simple enough. Add a new .htaccess file in `sub-domain-folder` with the following lines to redirect all calls/angular routes to `index.html` file within the sub-folder:

```
#Inside sub-domain-folder .htaccess file:

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

These same lines were present in `.htaccess` file in main domain folder `public_html`, just copied it from the same file into a new file in sub-domain folder.

Comment: This solved my problem too. And open ai was useless in this case. Thanks.